# Where to export i18n mode for menus in features?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using a combination of Entity Translation and Node Translation for a site and when I go and set up the menu, I need to edit each menu and select Translate and Localize.

Where is the feature to export this?

Answer (score 2):

This is stored in the menu itself. Menu_links aside, the menu features wil be stored in some custom.inc file.